# Siva Purana is a Mahapurana or Upapurana?

Tags: puranas, shiva-purana

There are 18 Mahapuranas and 18 Upapuranas according to tradition. Devi Bhagavad Upapurana lists all of them. Here, Sivapurana is listed as an Upapurana. However, Kurmapurana (a Mahapurana) also lists the names of Puranas. There, Sivapurana is listed as a Mahapurana. But, there is a catch. It says it lists 18 Mahapuranas, but the list has 19 names! The other 18 names are the names that are present in Devi Bhagavad. Now, Mahapurana's number is 18. There is no doubt about it. So, where to place Sivapurana?

Comment: According to me, Śiva Purāṇa mentioned under Upapurāṇa list of Devī Bhāgvata Purāṇa, may most possible be Śivadharma Purāṇa (which is mentioned in some other upapurāṇa lists). If you notice clearly, in Kūrma Purāṇa (1.1.13-20), there is an upapurāṇa named 'Śivadharma'.

Comment: @Bingming In that case, Siva purana would not be part of mahapurana also according to devi bhagavat

Comment: According to a hypothesis, the Vāyu Purāṇa in some lists actually refers to Śiva Purāṇa.

Comment: Most of the mahāpurāṇa lists I have (I have 15 lists from various Purāṇas), mention Śiva Purāṇa among the mahāpurāṇas. The exceptions are Garuḍa Purāṇa & Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa. The Garuḍa Purāṇa list mentions Āditya Purāṇa as a mahāpurāṇa (unlike any other mahāpurāṇa list). And Āditya Purāṇa is not surviving anymore. Anyway, since 13 lists mention Śiva Purāṇa as a mahāpurāṇa, I don't think there should be any doubt.

Comment: According to me, we should take more than 18 Mahāpurāṇas, so that we can accomodate Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa.

Comment: @Bingming then Mahapuranas will be 19 in number that is absurd.